# How do I add a border on a Angular Material textarea field?

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I'm using Angular with Material Design components.  How can I add a border around a textarea input field using CSS?

Example textarea from https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[What the default textarea looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRbW1.png)

Comment: Use appearance property on the form-field: `<mat-form-field appearance="outline">`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

if you add `appearance="outline"` to your `mat-form-field` it will add a border around your field

source: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview

Comment: Make sure you're adding the attribute to the mat-form-field element not the matInput element, i.e., <mat-form-field appearance="outline"><textarea matInput formControlName="myfield" rows="4"></textarea></mat-form-field>

Answer (score 3):

```html
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
```